# Incrementing area of convex hull

Tags: python, math, geometry

I want to use convex hull to draw a line around a list of points. However, I would like for the area to be larger than just minimum convex hull. How do I achieve that. P.S. I am using scipy.spatial implementation of ConvexHull, however it finds only the minimum area around list of points.

[image]

Comment: The operation you are looking for is called [*buffering*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_%28GIS%29) in Geo Information Systems. However, it looks like scypi doesn't support it, however. Getting it right also isn't trivial around the corners, so if you can pull in GDAL (or similar), you get it [right out of the box](http://www.gdal.org/classOGRGeometry.html#af1b450af88d10c763e5fb86e056fb307).

Answer (score 5):

```py
from scipy.spatial  import ConvexHull
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import math

def PointsInCircum(eachPoint,r,n=100):
    return [(eachPoint[0] + math.cos(2*math.pi/n*x)*r,eachPoint[1] + math.sin(2*math.pi/n*x)*r) for x in range(0,n+1)]


def bufferPoints (inPoints, stretchCoef, n):
    newPoints = []
    for eachPoint in inPoints:
        newPoints += PointsInCircum(eachPoint, stretchCoef, n)
    newPoints = np.array(newPoints)
    newBuffer = ConvexHull (newPoints)

    return newPoints[newBuffer.vertices]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    points = np.array([[-2,3], [2,4], [-2,-2], [2,-1], [1,-1], [-0.5, 0.5]])
    plt.scatter(points[:,0], points[:,1])
    plt.show()
    convh = ConvexHull(points)#Get the first convexHull (speeds up the next process)

    stretchCoef = 1.2
    pointsStretched = bufferPoints (points[convh.vertices], stretchCoef, n=10)
    plt.scatter(points[:,0], points[:,1])
    plt.scatter(pointsStretched[:,0], pointsStretched[:,1], color='r')
    plt.show()
```

So I updated the above code. It creates a circle of points around each of the first set of ConvexHull vertices and then creates a new ConvexHull.

Here is the output of this code [Plot View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xxXZd.png)

Answer (score 3):

Here is an idea to solve the exact problem you have on paper:

```
from scipy.spatial  import ConvexHull
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

if __name__ == '__main__':
    points = np.array([[-2,3], [2,4], [-2,-2], [2,-1], [1,-1], [-0.5, 0.5]])
    plt.scatter(points[:,0], points[:,1])
    plt.show()
    convh = ConvexHull(points)

    stretchCoef = 1.2
    pointsStretched = points[convh.vertices]*stretchCoef
    plt.scatter(points[:,0], points[:,1])
    plt.scatter(pointsStretched[:,0], pointsStretched[:,1], color='r')
    plt.show()
```

pointsStretched find the new points for your new convex hull.
Using a stretching coefficient works here because you have the points on each of the vertices of the convexhull on different quadrants, but I think you get the idea of how to solve this. One way is to find the points in your stretched convexhull, which will be along the same vector as the initial points.

Comment: This is a nice solution. But it also moves points/boundaries that are further from the origin relatively further out. From the drawing it looks like a equidistant buffer is needed. Of course, the exact buffer of a polygon is usually not again a polygon.

Comment: Absolutely correct dhke, appreciate you pointing that out. To address this, one could change this algorithm to computer different scaling coefficients for each point, where the computation takes as an input the size of the border.