# How to plot lines around images in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, convex-hull

I have two lists with the coordinates of points that I want to draw using matplotlib: hx and hy, and i have a function which draws these points as images: plotImage.

Now I would like to plot a line between these points, but the line should go somehow around the pictures. It doesn't have to go excctly by the borders of the images, the important thing is that it doesn't overlap with the pictures.

Here is an example, the green line is what I have now (its the convex hull), and the red line is an example of how the line should look like.
[image: Example]

Here's my code:

```
def plotImage(xData, yData, im):
    for x, y in zip(xData, yData):
        bb = Bbox.from_bounds(x,y,10,10)
        bb2 = TransformedBbox(bb,ax.transData)
        bbox_image = BboxImage(bb2,
                            norm = None,
                            origin=None,
                            clip_on=False)

        bbox_image.set_data(im)
        ax.add_artist(bbox_image)

fig=plt.figure()
ax=fig.add_subplot(111)
img = plt.imread('pic.png')

gx = list(map(lambda x: x - 5, hx)) #  so the center of the picture is in the point I want to plot 
gy = list(map(lambda y: y - 5, hy)) #(without this, the image is drawn so that the picture's left bottom corner is in my point)

plotImage(gx,gy,img)
plt.plot(hx, hy, 'g-', markersize=10)
```

So my question is: how to calculate this red hull?

Comment: does the red line have to be precise? Does it have to have as many vertices as the green one?

Comment: You can use this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33831516/incrementing-area-of-convex-hull

Answer (score 0):

A example using [Incrementing area of convex hull](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33831516/incrementing-area-of-convex-hull,it) can be applied to your case.

```
from scipy.spatial import ConvexHull
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

gx = [-2, 2, -2, 2, 1, -0.5]
gy = [3, 4, -2, -1, -1, 0.5]

points = np.array((gx, gy)).T
convh = ConvexHull(points)
stretchCoef = 1.2
pointsStretched = points[convh.vertices]*stretchCoef

gx_new = pointsStretched[..., 0]
gy_new = pointsStretched[..., 1]
```

Comment: This works very well for points, but when I try it with pictures it usually still overlaps some of them : https://i.imgur.com/RFYksbc.jpg

I'm trying to get the vector from a point inside the hull and adding a vector in that direction to all the hull points